# Threejs and 3D Tiles (from Cesium)

Tags: three.js, streaming, tiles, cesiumjs

I am currently in charge of exploring options to display large 3D geological models on a web page. They are built by the geologists with GeoModeller and exported using Cinema 4D to .DAE, or .OBJ. Once displayed, the model should be interactive and link to a database (this part is manageable from my side).

The issue: the models can be really big and I'm concerned that they could cause crashes and render slowly.

Solution considered so far: threejs + 3D Tiles (from cesium).

Questions: Is combining threejs and 3D Tiles actually doable? It is according to 3D Tiles presentation page but I am not a programmer and I have no idea how to implement it.

Is there another obvious solution to my problem?

Resources: What these 3D models look like: http://advancedgwt.com/wp-content/uploads/blog/63.jpg

What 3D Tiles does when combined with Cesium (but we don't want a globe here! ): http://cesiumjs.org/NewYork

Comment: Have you come across this? https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/648

Comment: @Peter O. did you make any progress on getting a 3d tile implementation working?

Comment: @lpic: I only edited this post; you meant to ask "ashdeb". If you're interested in getting answers (which I don't have, unfortunately), consider starting a bounty on this question.

Comment: @Ipic no. I haven't had the occasion to try since I posted this question since the project I was working on temporarily changed direction. I'm still interested in an answer or some help though.

Answer (score 5):

ThreeJS has everything needed to implement a 3DTiles Viewer

Here's an implementation (by me) : https://github.com/ebeaufay/3DTilesViewer

Here's another one by NASA: https://github.com/NASA-AMMOS/3DTilesRendererJS

The viewer is not too difficult to implement but tiling and multi-leveling gigabytes of mesh data, there's a challenge. Luckily, I have code to do just that so hit me up if you're interested.

Comment: Here's another 3dtiles renderer for three.js https://github.com/nytimes/three-loader-3dtiles/

Comment: Emeric, thank you, these are super helpful. As you guessed, the viewer side of things is fairly easy but processing the mesh is quite a bit of an undertaking. What is the best way to get in touch?

Comment: Hi, Send me a mail. emericbeaufays@gmail.com